# Does kotlin support default argument on generics like lists or maps

Tags: function, generics, kotlin, methods

I see that kotlin does not support this:

```
fun testDefaultListArg(listArg:MutableList<String>=mutableListOf()) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to make **listArg** parameter accepte a default list instance value ?

Thanks

Comment: It does. Just add spaces around the `=` sign. Add a space after the `:` while you're at it. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: @JBNizet This is a typo, I agree, but it is one that may bug several people in future and the behaviour is reproducible. So I turned your comment into an answer.

Comment: And the reason this doesn't work is probably that the Kotlin parser sees `>=` as a single token, so the generic never closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn the comment given by JBNizet into an answer:
You have to **put spaces before and after the *equal* (`=`) sign**, like this:

```kotlin
fun testDefaultListArg(listArg: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()) {
    // do what you think you have to do here
}
```